# String formatting with MYSQL -- PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to add **WHERE id = '$id'** to the end of my $query string?  My $query string reads as:

```
 $query = 'UPDATE students SET ' . join (' , ', $sqlConditions);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$query = 'UPDATE students SET ' . join (' , ', $sqlConditions) . ' WHERE id = "' . $id . '"';
```

If $id is just a number (most likely) you can do...

```
$query = 'UPDATE students SET ' . join (' , ', $sqlConditions) . ' WHERE id = ' . $id;
```

Also use mysql_real_escape_string() as ZombieHunter replied in his answer.

Comment: This returns, for example, ''UPDATE students SET lastname = 'test' WHERE id = "$id"  It does not reveal the value of the variable :/

Answer (score 2):

Do **not** append variables directly. Use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to avoid potential SQL injections!

I strongly encourage you to read this page about SQL injections:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

If `$sqlConditions` contains more than one condition (as the variable name states), this is a dangerous operation. Anyway, if you really want to use it this way, you need to put it after the WHERE condition.

```
$query = 'UPDATE students SET column = value WHERE ' . join(' , ', $sqlConditions) . ' AND id = ' . mysql_real_escape_string($id);
```

If `$sqlConditions` contains the SET statement this is a dangerous operation too. Use the actual column names together with `mysql_real_escape_string()`:

```
$query = 'UPDATE students SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2 WHERE id = ' . mysql_real_escape_string($id);
```